# How do you iterate through the list of parameters passed through a function?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, local-variables

I know `locals().keys()` prints out `dict_keys([parameter1, parameter2, parameter3])`

How do I just get the this list of parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
 [i for i in locals().keys()]
```

this could help you, just iterate through it using a list comprehension.

```
In [4]: [i for i in locals().keys()]
Out[4]:
['__name__',
 '__doc__',
 '__package__',
 '__loader__',
 '__spec__',
 '__builtin__',
 '__builtins__',
 '_ih',
 '_oh',
 '_dh',
 'In',
 'Out',
 'get_ipython',
 'exit',
 'quit',
 '_',
 '__',
 '___',
 '_i',
 '_ii',
 '_iii',
 '_i1',
 '_1',
 '_i2',
 '_2',
 '_i3',
 '_i4']
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understand this!! I think it's too advanced for me!

Comment: your question asked for an iterative solution, so this code iteratively goes through all parameters one by one and returns you a list of parameters in the object. the other answer uses a different method, using list(), which has the same result.

Comment: How on Earth does this qualify as advanced? This user added 9 characters to your original code to do exactly what you needed...

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get list of parameters

```
    list(locals().keys())
```

Comment: Perfect!! Will accept this answer as soon as my cooldown period ends